# Incorrect values on Highcharts (compared to input)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have a (Highcharts) graph with a percentage over time. The input for my series looks something like:

```
series: [{
    name: "Percentage",
    data: [
        [1472515200000, 49],
        [1472601600000, 48.83],
        [1472688000000, 49.6],
        [1472774400000, 48.77]
    ]
}]
```

However on the actual chart (areaspline) I get different values:

- 30 Aug, 48.91
- 31 Aug, 49.36
- 1 Sep, 49.6
- 2 Sep, 48.87

Not entirely sure why this is the case, I'm assuming it's because the graph has a datetime type and it's figuring out the average over time. Is there a way I can make the values exact as they are input? Couldn't find anything in docs

Thanks for any ideas/help/advice.

---

Upon further research, it seems like it's not so much a Highcharts problem but a React one. I seem to be getting different values on each render. Will look into this further and update for the curious.

---

Problem seemed to be related to React re-rendering and therefore recalculating my percentage values - not a Highcharts issue. Thanks for everyone who commented, bit of a wild goose chase.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for that, since series looks pretty normal.

Comment: I've missed the question, try to recreate the issue or paste the code you use. In the demo here, it works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/82zph5no/

Answer (score 0):

Jamie, to make the input values be taken literally, you need to either leave the `type` value of your x-axis unset or change it to `type: 'literal'`.

Here's a basic fiddle I created with your data to show how it can be interpreted exactly as input (vs. converted to dates): http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/vtLswcex/1/

```
$(function () {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      thousandsSep: ','     // adds comma for axis labels
    }
  });
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: "Percentage",
      data: [
        [1472515200000, 49],
        [1472601600000, 48.83],
        [1472688000000, 49.6],
        [1472774400000, 48.77]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

Note that I've added formatting for the x-axis labels, as well as a thousands separator in the `Highcharts.setOptions()` function, so that your labels will be more easily readable as trillions.

Does this help answer your question? If you are instead looking for a better way to format time-specific data, the comment by @morganfree is well worth looking into.

Comment: I think, you've missed the point on the question. The Y values are being corrupted. Dates are pretty ok, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @VladimirM I agree with you that the dates look OK if that's indeed what the OP is aiming for, but I based my answer on their statement "values exact as they are input." That's why I suggested the linear approach. I'm curious to learn precisely what's needed here.

Comment: Mike - I think @VladimirM's point is that the values in question are the `y` values, not the `x` values. If you look at the question, compare the `y` values in the data to the `y` values in the stated output.

Comment: @jlbriggs Thanks so much for the clarification. I missed these nuances in the question and it looks like the OP managed to suss out what was going on.